Is there any way to take input from user while running the python script using Squish. #Squish
I have a below scenario:
In my script, I am entering the credential and logging to the application, after login it asks for text code that is sent to the mobile device.
Currently, through code only I want to ask user to input the code and navigate to for next actions.
Is there any way to do it in squish.
Note: I am automating QT desktop application that is developed in Linux.
I tried input(prompt), but it is not working.

You can use testInteraction API (https://doc.qt.io/squish/squish-api.html#testinteraction-functions) provided by Squish.
Example of one of the functions mentioned in the manual:
name = testInteraction.input("Type in your name and press one of buttons below.")
if name == "":
    testInteraction.warning("It's sad you don't want to share your name.")
else:
    testInteraction.information("Hello %s!" %name)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Community, the question is asked for a very specific context, for use with a specific product. And my answer is as direct as possible - there is an API for that, here is the documentation, here is an example. It would help if this bot/AI tool would mention what seems unclear, because "it is unclear" is close to "it does not work".
